# Linux user service cannot be started but the service exists in /lib/systemd/system and linked

Tags: linux, mount, systemd, services

I have the following service unit defined in `/lib/systemd/system/`

```
[Unit]
Description=Kafka and Zookeeper 3 node ensemble
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target
ConditionPathExists=!/opt/

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvrionmentFile=/etc/environment
User=kafkacluster
Group=kafkacluster
ExecStart=${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-startj.sh ${KAFKA_HOME}
ExecStop=${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-stopj.sh ${KAFKA_HOME}
Restart=on-failure
SyslogIdentifier=kafkacluster

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After this I have run the following command

`systemctl enable /lib/systemd/system/kafkacluster.service`

Which showed that the files have a soft-link `/etc/systemd/system`. Now when I run

`systemctl start kafkacluster.service`

I am getting the following error:

`Unit kafkacluster.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status kafkacluster.service' for details.`

But since the service is there, i am not sure what else is missing. Could anyone point me to the right direction?

**TYPO**      ConditionPathExists=/opt/

output of `systemctl kafkacluster.service`

```
kafkacluster.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: so you should show us `systemctl status kafkacluster.service` :)

Comment: paste the logs. check systemd settings too.

Comment: @rajaganesh87        No logs sir! Empty files :)

Answer (score 1):

> ConditionPathExists=!/opt/

Please note the following: If the absolute path name passed to ConditionPathExists= is prefixed with an exclamation mark ("!"), the test is negated, and the unit is only started if the path does not exist.

Don't you really have the /opt/ directory in your system?

Also, check that the ${KAFKA_HOME} variable is defined.

Comment: Still no difference. And I do have those environment variables checked via `cat /etc/environment`.